# can't install. pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, pycharm

The error message when running `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'e:\django-pos-master\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Use
rs\\asada\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-82_9dan8\\pillow_f761b25e426a43f6891c453cc664459a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\asada\\AppData\\Local\\Te
mp\\pip-install-82_9dan8\\pillow_f761b25e426a43f6891c453cc664459a\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\
r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\asada\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lt_0q0si\install-
record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\django-pos-master\venv\include\site\python3.9\Pillow' Check the logs for full com
mand output.
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your requirements.txt file? Can you install packages individually, (i.e. pip install django)? Are you in the working environment?

Comment: Django~=2.1.0
Pillow==5.2.0
pytz==2018.5

My python version is 3.9

Comment: It looks like your problem is with Pillow, with this you can install all but those packages where you have the problem: `cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 pip install`.
Anyway, maybe that Pillow version is too low for Python 3.9, try with the newest Pillow version.

Comment: Pillow 5.2 - 5.4 only runs on pyhton 3.4 to 3.7.
I dont know how to downgrade pyhton to 3.7 from 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your pip: run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: already did this but the error remain same

Answer (score 2):

The Pillow version is not compatible with Python 3.9, try with Pillow~=8.0:

[image]

Comment: But my code requirements are
Django~=2.1.0
Pillow==5.2.0
pytz==2018.5

requirements.txt file

Comment: I would suggest you to install different condas environment with the different package versions and see where the code works. For example:
1) `conda create -n env_37 python == 3.7` → requirements: Django~=2.1.0 Pillow==5.2.0 pytz==2018.5
2) `conda create -n env_39 python == 3.9` → requirements: Django~=2.1.0 Pillow==8.0 pytz==2018.5